# Monorepo for ASP.NET Core Web API micro services

Tags: c#, git, asp.net-web-api, monorepo

I am wondering if `monorepo` is the best solution for creating a micro services based project?

Is there any better solution than making loosely coupled services and then push them into one repo?

Is there any documentation or resources for making this mess?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think there's no "best" solution that fits all microservice based projects - it depends on what your services do, who writes the services, how the data access and communication between the services is managed, but also on how your development team is set up.

From two years of experience i can tell you that a monorepo is a very viable way to go, but most of the patterns you will use support splitting up the code into multiple repos anyway.

In a monorepo the obvious benefit is having the possibility to share code between projects, like domain entites, enums or extension methods. *But*: that stuff can also be compiled into a neat nuget package which is then consumed by your different service repos.

Another important aspect is versioning and dependency management; in other words: keeping your services compatible with each other. Again, a monorepo scores big points because with the right ci/cd setup you almost don't have to do anything. In a split codebase/repo structure this is also fairly doable. If you're using API versioning then this is less of a worry - if you don't, then you are going to have to a bit more legwork to actually have loosely coupled services. (You could also configure your ci pipeline to do a compatibility check before deploying a service)

There are a lot of considerations that you should think about beforehand. Some of these gave me a headache:

- How are your data sources set up? Can multiple services access a shared data source?
- How do the services talk to each other? (they always do)
- How are your services consumed? (web frontends, apps, .net clients etc.)
- How do you change, update and/or even refactor core components of your services?
- How is your team set up, can they handle a mono-/split repo?
- How do you debug a service that has dependencies to other services?
- Are there other teams adding services to your project, maybe even in different programming languages?

The major deciding factor for me was the extra time that i would have to invest into keeping multiple repos compatible.

**TL;DR**

- If you provide micro services platform that other developers can add their own services on to, a split code base would probably be better.
- If you develop micro services for a specific project with a clearly defined scope, it's nicer to work with a monorepo.

Comment: + How will you update each microservice when a new .NET version is released? (3.1 -> 6.0). The .NET Core repo has a mechanism somehow somewhere that determines the target framework globally.

Comment: If you don't share .net code between your services and you containerize them, you can upgrade one service at a time, whenever you want. In my project we use shared .net libraries for the app startup and configuration stuff, so we "had to" upgrade everything to have a "compilable" code-base. (We use docker, so we had to bump the container .net runtime version too) Communication between services shouldn't be an issue, since the .net version does not affect the interfaces / models used.

Comment: splitting the code is awesome to make each developer works independently but on the other hand we need to monitor and control each modifcation on the project in case it is a giant one , so having 10 developer working on the same project is not an easy task to control the coherence between the project parts